# JDK 8u31 Not Installing on Windows 10 Preview

Tags: installation, java, windows-10-preview, jdk

I'm trying out the Windows 10 Preview on my computer, and I tried to install Java and the JDK.

Java installed fine from [Java.com](http://www.java.com/en/), but intalling the JDK from the [JDK8 Download Page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) gave me the following error:

[image: Java error message]

(And I can't find the MSI anywhere.)

I hadn't seen this before, even when installing the same version of Java (8u31) on Windows 7 earlier.

Is this a Windows 10 bug, or is it just something I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: This is very likely an incompatibility with Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there are two following reasons:
1. Your downloaded file has changed extension into .msi instead of .exe. (No extension in my case). So you must change manually into .exe for downloaded file.
2. If you want to run .msi file, you must install Windows Installer firstly.

Comment: So you're suggesting that somewhere in the download process, an exe file got renamed to an msi file and the fix for that is to just rename it back?  I must be misunderstanding your answer.

Comment: @fixer1234 : Yes, I guest that MIME type of downloaded file was affected by request from browser or response from Oracle server.